# getResource returns null on one server but not on the other

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, aix

I run 2 tomcat instances on two different servers. I deploy the same war file on both of them but it doesn't work the same way.

On instnace one everything is fine while on instance two I get a NullPointerException because the variable "resource" in the "listAllConfigIds" method is NULL.

```
public List<String> listAllConfigIds() {
    URL resource = SomeClass.class.getResource("./");
    LOG.debug("Loading from resource " + resource);
    return Arrays.asList(new File(resource.getPath()).list()).stream().filter(s -> !s.toLowerCase().contains("."))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I started tomcat with the same vm args on AIX. Any ideas what the problem coud be?

Comment: so, it's quite likely that that resource is present on one server, and not on the other.

Comment: But I can see the resources in the webapps folder. The folders are identical.

Comment: Are those two environments run on different systems? e.g. one is Windows and another Linux?

Comment: Both are AIX machines

Comment: And you build them in a same way? there are no build process differences?

Comment: I uploaded the same war file to both machines via the manager gui

Comment: Delete exploded folders and .war files in `webapps` folder and try again. Also, try to get resource via `.getClassLoader().getResource("path..");`

Comment: It works with getClassLoader and the absolute path to the resource. Well I guess better than a NPE. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the relative path I am now building the absolute path:

```
SomeClass.class.getName().substring(0, SomeClass.class.getName().lastIndexOf(".")).replace(".", "/");
```

Strip the last part and replace "." with "/"